# Adding Context to Class Based View Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a problem with showing a queryset of a specific model in my Gym project. I have tried many different query's but none is working

the models:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True, null=True)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exercises',blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)

class Breakdown(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='excercise',blank=True, null=True)
    repetitions = models.IntegerField()
```

I am trying to showing the `repetitions` in the Breakdown model which has a ForeignKey relation with Exercise which has a ForeignKey relation with Workout

views.py

```
class home(ListView):
    model = Workout
    template_name = 'my_gym/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'workouts'

class workout_details(ListView):
    model = Exercise
    template_name = 'my_gym/start_workout.html'
    context_object_name = 'exercises'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['breakdown'] = Exercise.objects.filter(breakdown=self.breakdown)
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('workout/<int:pk>/', workout_details.as_view(), name='workout'),
]
```

template:

```
{% for e in exercises %}
{{ e.name }}
{{ breakdown.repetitions }}
{% endfor %}
```

My question what is my mistake here that is either getting me an error or not showing the required data set. my objective is the choose from the home page a Workout from list and next page to be the list of exercises with the repitions related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_context_data()` is a method calculated for view, not a loop to use inside a template or something similar. You have set nice relations, use them properly.

Firstfully, change `related_name` here to something that will not be confusing:

```
class Breakdown(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='breakdowns', blank=True, null=True)
```

With that done, delete whole `get_context_data()` and change template to:

```
{% for e in exercises %}
    {{ e.name }}
    {% for b in e.breakdowns.all %}
        {{ b.repetitions }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why is all the exercises showing in the `workout_details` whatever workout option I choose in the `home` url

Comment: @A_K because it's also `ListView` and you didn't specified `queryset` in any way, so it takes all objects. You should use `DetailView` to get specific `Workout` then get related exercises with `workout.exercises.all` (assuming, that you will set this: `context_object_name = 'workout').